# How to put dice rolls in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dice

Dear stackoverflowers,

Could someone help me further with this excercise:

Throw a dice 40 times. The throws has to be put in an array. If a throw is the same as the previous one, it has to be grouped between brackets. It'll cost you 1 point per throw, and if you throw two the same numbers in a row, you get 5 points. Print the info out for the user(like: "Congratz! You earned 5 points") , and how many points the user has left. I dont really know from how many points the user starts but lets just give it 40.

This is my code so far

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
function rollDice() {
           var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
           var status = document.getElementById("status");

           var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
           console.log("You rolled "+d1+".");
           if(d1)

  }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="die1" class="dice">0</div>

    <button onclick="rollDice()"> Roll the dice </button>
    <h2 id="status" style="clear:left":> </h2>
</body>
```

Id like to know how to put this into an array and if a throw is the same as the previous one, it logs to the console 5 points.
I'm a beginner so please bear with me.

Thanks in advance,

Youssef

Comment: _"it has to be grouped between brackets"_ - What does that mean?

Comment: This looks like you're just trying to get a free solution to a homework problem, without trying to finish it yourself. Perhaps if you narrowed the question down a bit, it would be more on-topic.

Comment: that it will automatically group the double numbers between brackets, for example: 1 4 6 (5 5) *message saying you gained 5 points* 6 1 3 (2 2 2 2)  etc.

Comment: Try using a global var for the array. But a better idea would be to wrap all of that in an immediate function, declare your array in the top level of that, and add rollDice() with a event handler, instead of in the html.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can declare an array as follows:

```
var diceRolls = [];
```

To add something to an array:

```
diceRolls.push(diceRoll);
```

To check previous result for equality. Note shoudl also check the previous element exists in the array.

```
if (diceRolls[diceRolls.length - 1] === diceRoll)
     // do stuff
```

Hope that gets you started. W3cschools is a great way to get started

Comment: "W3cschools is a great way to get started" Maybe so, but MDN is a much more complete and accurate resource.

Comment: and where am I supposed to add the array? Inside the <script> elements?

Comment: All javascript should go within script tags. In your case you want to add the array declaration above the function roll dice and below the script tag. Good luck

Comment: Thnx! But i'm wondering why i get the message: Uncaught ReferenceError: d1 is not defined. Cause i replaced your 'diceRoll' with my d1

Comment: Could you show your modified code please?

Comment: I aint getting the message anymore but now I am trying to log to the console a message saying : Gratz! You gained 5 points!' after you rolled two the same numbers after each other. Can you please show why it isnt helping?

Comment: <script>
   
               
     var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
     
      var diceRolls = [];
    
     
    function rollDice() {
               var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
               var status = document.getElementById("status");               
               var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
               console.log("You rolled "+d1+".");
               diceRolls.push(d1);
      
                       
      }
        if(diceRolls[diceRolls.length - 1] === d1) {
          console.log("You won 5 points!");
      }     
      </script>

Comment: Suggest putting this into jsfiddle for help:
http://jsfiddle.net/ and sharing that.